# SQL sum, grouping by another table

Tags: sql

Consider I have a table `t1` with a single column `a`, and it has values, say

```
a
-
5
10
15
17
```

I want to write a single SQL query that does the following. Basically, I want to know the sum of all values up to the value in the table `t1`.

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM t2 WHERE value<=5
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(value) FROM t2 WHERE value<=10
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(value) FROM t2 WHERE value<=15
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(value) FROM t2 WHERE value<=17;
```

If someone changes the value in `a`, like delete or insert more elements, I have to rewrite the above query. Is there a query that always works automatically?

Here is the [DB fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7QidZWNJysTRQDMZvaWp2/0).

Comment: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) please

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: assuming every col has a value of 1 you want to have an output like 1,2,3,4,5... ?

Comment: `a[1]` . .  `a[n]` is not how a column value is referenced.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you appears to want :

```
SELECT SUM(case when bound<=a[1] then value else 0 end),
       . . . 
FROM table t;
```

After edit with fiddle, you can use `subquery` instead of `UNION`  :

```
select *, (select sum(t2.value) from t2 where t2.value <= t1.a)
from t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more clear with a join than a subquery, but just personal preference.

```
SELECT
    t1.a,
    SUM(COALESCE(t2.value, 0))
FROM
    t1
LEFT JOIN
    t2
ON
    t2.value <= t1.a
GROUP BY
    t1.a
```